# Random number geneation in c# using normal distr

Tags: c#, random, numbers

i am new to c# and i am trying to generate numbers ifrom normal distribution in c#. I serched the web and i found only some code. I would like to use a ready built in function and not a code!! any suggestions?

Comment: go through this hope it helps -- :http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data-in-c.aspx

Comment: thank you for this response, but i've already found this. This code provides methods for cauchy distr. I would like a statistic library on c# and i can;t find anything excpet for code by individuals

Comment: Why the down votes?  I think they don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will still need to do a little coding too:

1. Define your normal distribution.
2. Sample from it.

N.B You need to define it once and then sample as opposed to re-define.

Maybe this little class can help, then you can just use it in your code where you need...

```
    public class BoxMullerNormal
        {                       
            private MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal normal;

            public BoxMullerNormal(double mean = 0,double std = .01)
            {
                normal = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal(mean,std);            
            }

            public override dynamic getRandom()
            {
                // Implementation Uses C#MathNet.Numerics Normal Distribution Sampling
                return normal.Sample();                          
            }
}
```

Initialize the class at the start of your app to define the normal, then just call `getRandom()` every time to sample from it. You can also add the class to once of your existing Interfaces.